# oracle how catch error in sql query in cursor block

Tags: oracle, exception, cursor

how can i catch error in sql query in block exception? In the example below (division by zero - **select (5 / 0) as example  from dual**), the exception block is not executed.

```
FUNCTION getData(p_result out integer)   
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR select (5 / 0) as example  from dual;
  
  p_result := 1;
  RETURN my_cursor;
  
exception 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    p_result := 0;
END getData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're *catching* the error at the wrong place. It is raised when function is called, not when it is created. Here's an example.

First, your function:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  FUNCTION getData(p_result out integer)
  3    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  4  AS
  5    my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  6  BEGIN
  7    OPEN my_cursor FOR select (5 / 0) as example  from dual;
  8
  9    p_result := 1;
 10    RETURN my_cursor;
 11
 12  exception
 13      WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14      p_result := 0;
 15  END getData;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Calling it; I'm just displaying the error message; you'd do something else.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_res  integer;
  3    rc     sys_refcursor;
  4    l_exam number;
  5  begin
  6    rc := getdata(l_res);
  7    loop
  8      fetch rc into l_exam;
  9      exit when rc%notfound;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_exam);
 11    end loop;
 12    close rc;
 13  exception
 14    when others then
 15      dbms_output.put_line('Error: ' || sqlerrm);
 16  end;
 17  /
Error: ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, Littlefoot. You're right, if I call this function in Oracle, I get an error. The problem is that I call it from PHP and the oci_error function does not return an error.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry, I don't know PHP so I can't assist any futher.

Answer (score 0):

```
-------Just User this function------
------------------------------------
FUNCTION getData(p_result out integer)   
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR select (5 / NULLIF(0,0)) as example  from dual;
  
  p_result := 1;
  RETURN my_cursor;
  
exception 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    p_result := 0;
END getData;
```